# Are there any specific import commands required for the distance_matrix while using Google Maps API with Python?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I am following tutorial steps to calculate the distance between two places using the Google Maps API with Python in Jupyter Notebook. For some reason I can never run the Distance_Matrix. My code is as given below:

```
with open('apikey.txt') as f:
    apikey = f.readline()
    f.close
import googlemaps    
import gmaps
import gmaps.datasets

import pandas as pd
from itertools import tee

gmaps.configure(api_key=apikey)


#Define location 1 and 2
Durango = (37.2753,-107.880067)
SF = (37.7749,-122.419416)
#Create the map
fig = gmaps.figure()

#create the layer
layer = gmaps.directions.Directions(Durango, SF,mode='driving')
result = gmaps.distance_matrix(Durango, SF, mode='driving')['rows'][0]['elements'][0] 
distance = gmaps.distance_matrix([str(37.2753) + " " + str(-107.880067)], [str(37.7749) + " " + str(-122.419416)], mode='driving')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]

#Add the layer
fig.add_layer(layer)
fig
```

I get an error as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-d6e53b6bf32d> in <module>
     20 #create the layer
     21 layer = gmaps.directions.Directions(Durango, SF,mode='driving')
---> 22 result = gmaps.distance_matrix(Durango, SF, mode='driving')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]
     23 distance = gmaps.distance_matrix([str(37.2753) + " " + str(-107.880067)], [str(37.7749) + " " + str(-122.419416)], mode='driving')['rows'][0]['elements'][0]
     24 

AttributeError: module 'gmaps' has no attribute 'distance_matrix'
```

Can someone help me identify why this is happening? Thank you!

I am new to this so dont know what other information might be required for debugging....
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a link of the tutorial you are following?